# How to exchange multidimensional arrays from matlab to python/numpy and back?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, multidimensional-array

i think this code handles n-d correctly (please verify), and i've hacked it to be polymorphic, but it's ugly.  is there a better/more efficient way? i'm not sure it shares memory as much as possible.  i want to avoid `F order`ing cuz i'm guessing numpy/python are happier with `C`.  if i'm wrong on that, please enlighten me to any advantages of using `F` in this case.

specific questions (if this overall approach is best):

- does `array.array(.,numpy.ndarray.ravel)` copy data?  i suspect yes.  would there be a way to share it instead?  for instance, what would be the performance/memory sharing implications of using `numpy.nditer()`, `numpy.ndarray.flat`, or `numpy.ndarray.flatten` instead?  see http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/Why-ndarray-provides-four-ways-to-flatten-td38989.html
- i need an `array.peek` method, why isn't there one?
- if i can't have `array.peek`, is `array.append` as inefficient as i'm suspecting (copying the whole array again)?  i could have used `numpy.insert` or `numpy.append` instead (which cleans up the code because i don't have to special case the empty array), but i believe those do copy.
- are there any negative implications of `F order`?
- i believe `numpy.reshape` and `numpy.transpose` efficiently create `view`s without copying data -- but then, when the data is accessed, the access pattern will be all fragged up via the indirection through a bunch of layered `view`s.  doesn't this negate the whole point of `numpy`'s contiguous memory layout in the first place?
- in general, this type of information doesn't seem to be systematically laid out in any documentation i can find.  do i have to resort to reading `array`/`ndarray` src?

code

```
function f
sz = [2 4 3 2];
d = reshape(1:prod(sz),sz)
d = to_np(d)
d = from_np(d)
end

function p = to_np(p)
sz = size(p);
p = reshape(p,[1 numel(p)]); % Conversion to Python is only supported for 1-N vectors.
p = py.numpy.array(p); % if empty, type is always set to double cuz of https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6028
p = p.reshape(num2cell(fliplr(sz)));
t = 0:length(sz)-1;
t(end-[1 0]) = t(end-[0 1]);
p = p.transpose(num2cell(t));
end

function p = from_np(p)
sz = cellfun(@double,cell(p.shape));

method = 1;
switch method
    case 1
        empty = any(sz == 0);
        if empty
            p = py.numpy.insert(p,0,0); % casts 0 to p's type so we can later pop it for use with matlab's cast
        end
        p = py.array.array(p.dtype.char,p.ravel); % does this copy data -- how share memory?  any better to use py.numpy.nditer(p), p.flat, or p.flatten?
        % http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/Why-ndarray-provides-four-ways-to-flatten-td38989.html
        c = p.pop(); % i can has peek?
        if ~empty
            p.append(c); % i suspect this could be very inefficient, does it copy the whole thing again?
        end
    case 2
        p = py.numpy.insert(p,p.size,0); % numpy.insert / numpy.append copy the whole array, so maybe worse than array.append?
        p = py.array.array(p.dtype.char,p); % numpy.insert already flattened p
        c = p.pop();
end

p = cast(p,'like',c);
p = reshape(p,fliplr(sz));
t = 1:length(sz);
t([1 2]) = t([2 1]);
p = permute(p,t);
end
```

output

```
d(:,:,1,1) =
     1     3     5     7
     2     4     6     8
d(:,:,2,1) =
     9    11    13    15
    10    12    14    16
d(:,:,3,1) =
    17    19    21    23
    18    20    22    24
d(:,:,1,2) =
    25    27    29    31
    26    28    30    32
d(:,:,2,2) =
    33    35    37    39
    34    36    38    40
d(:,:,3,2) =
    41    43    45    47
    42    44    46    48
d = 
  Python ndarray with properties:

           T: [1x1 py.numpy.ndarray]
        base: [1x1 py.numpy.ndarray]
      ctypes: [1x1 py.numpy.core._internal._ctypes]
       dtype: [1x1 py.numpy.dtype]
       flags: [1x1 py.numpy.flagsobj]
        flat: [1x1 py.numpy.flatiter]
        imag: [1x1 py.numpy.ndarray]
    itemsize: 8
      nbytes: 384
        ndim: 4
        real: [1x1 py.numpy.ndarray]
       shape: [1x4 py.tuple]
        size: 48
     strides: [1x4 py.tuple]
    [[[[  1.   3.   5.   7.]
       [  2.   4.   6.   8.]]

      [[  9.  11.  13.  15.]
       [ 10.  12.  14.  16.]]

      [[ 17.  19.  21.  23.]
       [ 18.  20.  22.  24.]]]


     [[[ 25.  27.  29.  31.]
       [ 26.  28.  30.  32.]]

      [[ 33.  35.  37.  39.]
       [ 34.  36.  38.  40.]]

      [[ 41.  43.  45.  47.]
       [ 42.  44.  46.  48.]]]]
d(:,:,1,1) =
     1     3     5     7
     2     4     6     8
d(:,:,2,1) =
     9    11    13    15
    10    12    14    16
d(:,:,3,1) =
    17    19    21    23
    18    20    22    24
d(:,:,1,2) =
    25    27    29    31
    26    28    30    32
d(:,:,2,2) =
    33    35    37    39
    34    36    38    40
d(:,:,3,2) =
    41    43    45    47
    42    44    46    48
```

Comment: This is strongly dependent on the `py.numpy` package, right?  You might get other ideas from how `scipy.io.loadmat` loads `.mat` files.  It has to work with the `order=F` issue.  I believe `cells` are loaded as lists, and `structures` as dictionaries.

Comment: good idea to read `loadmat`, but i note that memory structure (i'll edit my question to make sure that emphasis comes across) may not be the same as storage structure, and certainly won't be "shared" (as in "no copies") in the way i'm looking for.  :)

Comment: I am thinking about writing an interface to pack/read n-d array on disk in both MATLAB and Python, sharing the same protocol defined by you. Am I giving you too much work?

Comment: @Mai - i don't understand your question -- you're welcome to use the code posted here obviously.  :)

Comment: Part of the reason you aren't getting more responses from `numpy` people is that we aren't sure where the MATLAB `py` interface leaves off, and familiar `numpy` code begins.  And these days the closest I get to MATLAB is `octave`.  So I can test things like `.mat` interfaces, but not `py`.

Comment: @hpaulj - thanks for the insight!  i added the bulleted list of specific questions, and all of them are pure `numpy` and can be addressed without referring to the code -- are any of them ambiguous? EDIT: well, not just `numpy`, but also `array.array`...

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to tackle these questions bit by bit, edit by edit

> - does array.array(.,numpy.ndarray.ravel) copy data? i suspect yes. would there be a way to share it instead? for instance, what would be the performance/memory sharing implications of using numpy.nditer(), numpy.ndarray.flat, or numpy.ndarray.flatten instead? see http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/Why-ndarray-provides-four-ways-to-flatten-td38989.html

`np.array` is the normal constructor of `numpy` arrays, particularlly when starting from lists.  In fact I get the impression, from timings, that it converts all of its inputs to lists (if arrays) and then back, giving it most control over the interpretation and dtype of the inputs.

I haven't used `np.ndarray` much, but it appears to be a more basic constructor, and is suitable if you want to make array with a preexisting data buffer.

```
In [333]: x=np.arange(10)
In [334]: y=np.array(x)

In [335]: x.__array_interface__
Out[335]: 
{'shape': (10,),
 'version': 3,
 'strides': None,
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'data': (158045400, False)}

In [336]: y.__array_interface__
Out[336]: 
{'shape': (10,),
 'version': 3,
 'strides': None,
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'data': (158072688, False)}
```

The number under 'data' is the pointer to its data buffer.  `y` is a copy of `x`, not a view.

Doing the same with `x.flatten().__array_interface__` shows that it too is a copy. `x.ravel().__array_interface__` is a view (same data pointer).

`x.reshape((-1,1)).__array_interface__` is a view

`x.shape = (-1,1)` in an inplace operation - not only doesn't it copy the data, it doesn't copy the metadata.

> - i need an array.peek method, why isn't there one?

What is `peek` supposed to do?  Sounds like a look-ahead function for an iterator or other serial access object.

> - if i can't have array.peek, is array.append as inefficient as i'm suspecting (copying the whole array again)? i could have used numpy.insert or numpy.append instead (which cleans up the code because i don't have to special case the empty array), but i believe those do copy.

`np.append` uses `np.concatenate`, which in turn does create a new array.  It's ok for adding a new value in array once or twice, but new users mistakenly try to use it iteratively.  Same for `np.insert`.  Python list append is better for iterative work.

There isn't a way of adding an element to a numpy array without making a copy.

> - are there any negative implications of F order?

Access time when indexing 2d arrays varies depending on the axis and C v F order.  Otherwise I wouldn't worry too much about it.

> - i believe numpy.reshape and numpy.transpose efficiently create views without copying data -- but then, when the data is accessed, the access pattern will be all fragged up via the indirection through a bunch of layered views. doesn't this negate the whole point of numpy's contiguous memory layout in the first place?

`reshape` and `transpose` change values like the `shape` and `strides`, but otherwise don't do anything to the data buffer.  It is a little faster to access one contiguous block of data in the buffer, which for a `C` order array means something like `x[3]` or `x[3,:]`.  But the striding mechanism is supposed to give reasonable speed to any regular pattern of access.

> - in general, this type of information doesn't seem to be systematically laid out in any documentation i can find. do i have to resort to reading array/ndarray src?

---

I missed the fact that half of questions focused on the Python `array` module, not `numpy`.  I haven't used it, but the documentation looks straight forward.  And testing:

```
In [420]: import array
In [421]: xa=array.array('i')  # create the array

In [422]: xa.fromlist(np.arange(10).tolist())
# can add elements in various ways, including all the list ones
# so to/from list is always an option

In [423]: xa
Out[423]: array('i', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [424]: xa[3]  # can be indexed like a list, not need for a peek
Out[424]: 3

In [425]: xa[8:]
Out[425]: array('i', [8, 9])
```

`ndarray` is not used as much as `np.array`, but is useful if you already have a data buffer.  And apparently an `array.array` qualifies:

```
In [426]: xn=np.ndarray((10,),int,buffer=xa)    
In [427]: xn
Out[427]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Modifying elements in `xa` also modify them in `xn`, because of the shared buffer

```
In [428]: xa[3]=30
In [429]: xn[3]
Out[429]: 30
```

Adding or deleting elements from `xa` is bound to mess up `xn`.  But `xn` can be reshaped, transposed, etc.  And inplace changes to `xn` (e.g. +=) are reflected in `xa`.  And anything that makes a copy of `xn` looses connections with `xa`.

Comment: the first question is asking if there is a way to make a standard array (https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) from a numpy ndarray that shares memory.  matlab can only convert from standard arrays, that's why i need that step.  flattening the ndarray is only part of this step.  would using `nditer` (or some other iterator) have exactly the same space/time efficiency as `.ravel`?  what about `.flat`?  you're suggesting `p.shape = (-1,1); array.array(.,p)` would be best of all?  when i try it, i get the error that the array has to be contiguous, which means making a copy.

Comment: `peek` should return like `pop` without removing the element.  again, this question and the next (about `append`) are regarding standard arrays, not numpy arrays.

Comment: without `peek`, i need to `pop` and `append` a value off a potentially large standard array.  i need the value so i can use matlab's `cast like` to match its type.  although it's only a single `append`, i worry it requires a copy of the whole array.  again, we're talking about standard arrays here, i know `numpy.append` copies.

Comment: regarding `F order` -- it's matlab's order, so i could avoid the `numpy.transpose` and matlab `permute` steps (i think).  but will this help me make fewer copies?  since it changes the order of elements wrt the flat standard array, i worry other `numpy` functions will depend on the order -- but you're saying either order behaves the same, except for the order of elements when `reshape`ing?

Comment: I've done almost nothing with the standard arrays; and don't know what's involved in converting to/from numpy.  Regarding `F order`, `loadmat` returns arrays with that order.  There may be numpy functions that prefer `C` order, but it is easy to convert the order.

Comment: I've added some notes on using `array.array`.

Comment: thanks for showing standard `array` can be indexed as a sequence type, i had overlooked that.  unfortunately, matlab doesn't allow indexing for `array`: www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/limitations-to-indexing-into-python-objects.html -- why doesn't `array` inherit from `collections.Sequence`?  the fact that `array` is not mentioned at docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange is why i missed this possibility.  indeed, in matlab, `x{1}`, `x(1)`, and `cell(x)` all work when x is a `list`, but not `array`.

Comment: i can make my own `peek.py` that uses sequence indexing and call it from matlab...

Comment: or i can call `x = p.tolist` and index that with `x{end}` -- but does this make a copy?  can i avoid making the copy?  :)

Comment: `py.operator.getitem(p,py.len(p)-1)` works for `array`!

Comment: Yes, the use of `[]` is a syntactic issue that does not easily translate across languages.

Comment: well that's not the issue here -- as shown, if `array` inherited from `collections.Sequence`, matlab can handle the indexing.

Comment: thanks for the pointer to the `ndarray` constructor, where is it documented?  why isn't it here? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-creation.html

Comment: ah i see it here http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html

Comment: why wouldn't using `numpy.array(array.array)` use the `numpy.ndarray(buffer=.)` memory-sharing?  do we know that it doesn't?  what about the other direction -- can i make `array.array(.,numpy.ndarray)` share memory?

Comment: well i verified that you don't get the memory sharing from `numpy.array(array.array)` -- i wonder why?  trying to use the `ndarray` constructor from matlab isn't working: `py.numpy.ndarray(py.tuple(num2cell(uint64(size(p,2)))),py.type(p(1)),pyargs('buffer',p))` where `p` is a `1xN` matlab array gives `Python Error: buffer is too small for requested array`

Comment: the issue here is something wrong with types - `py.numpy.ndarray(length(p)/8,py.type(p(1)),pyargs('buffer',p))` is the longest that works, and has garbage data.  `p` is matlab `uint8`, but `py.type(p(1))` is `int`.  `py.numpy.array(p)` makes an `ndarray` of `int64`. `f=py.operator.attrgetter('typecode'); f(p)` gives `B`

Comment: casting `p` to `double` makes it work -- but all matlab `int` types (`int`/`uint` `8`/`16`/`32`) have the above failure.  `int`/`uint` `64` give `Python Error: bad typecode (must be c, b, B, u, h, H, i, I, l, L, f or d)` -- makes sense, cuz it looks like `array.array` doesn't support an 8 byte int type, but i can't figure out how to expose the typecode matlab tried, or the src that does the conversion from matlab array to `array.array`...

Comment: alright, this works for all matlab int types 4 bytes or less, plus `single` and `double`: `py.numpy.ndarray(length(q),py.numpy.dtype(py.numpy.(class(q))),pyargs('buffer',q))`

Comment: huh, the fact that it needed to know the actual matlab class, rather than just python int, suggested to me that i was actually sharing the memory all the way from matlab to python -- but mutating items shows that they are copies.  i don't know how to reconcile those two facts...

Comment: I'm having trouble tracking your sequence of comments.  Maybe you could write up your own answer, and edit that as the ideas develop.  I don't have enough experience with the chat mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

anytime you pass a matlab array `p` (must be `1xN`) to a python function, matlab [automatically converts](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/passing-data-to-python.html#buialof-50) it to an [`array.array`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html).  this won't work for 8 byte ints in python 2.7, where there is no such `array.array`.  open questions:

- is it possible for these objects to share memory?
- where is the matlab src that actually does this?  it seems to be purposely hidden/opaque, not even in `<matlabroot>/toolbox/matlab/external/interfaces/python/+python/+internal/`.

here's how to create a `numpy.ndarray` that shares memory with that `array.array`:
`py.numpy.ndarray(length(p),py.numpy.dtype(py.numpy(class(p))),pyargs('buffer',‌​p))`.  mutating items shows that this memory is not shared all the way back to matlab's array.  open questions:

- would there be a way to share memory all the way back to matlab?
- why doesn't `numpy.array(array.array)` use the same buffer sharing as the `ndarray` constructor method?
- why isn't the `ndarray` [constructor](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) mentioned [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-creation.html)?
- the `ndarray` constructor needs to know the actual matlab class, just using python's `int` or `float` type (`py.type(p(1))`) results in incorrect interpretation of the buffer.  this isn't because memory is shared all the way back to matlab -- it's because `p(1)` is converted to a different python type when isolated (`int` or `float`) than when part of an array (where it will be one of the `array.array` types `b, B, h, H, i, I, f or d`).  for 4 byte ints, why does matlab use `i`/`I` instead of `l`/`L`?
- is there a way to share memory going the other way?  `array.array(.,numpy.ndarray)`

the way to index into `array.array` from matlab (for eg the last element) is `py.operator.getitem(p,py.len(p)-1)`.  for `numpy.ndarray`, it's `p.item(p.size - 1)`.

- why don't they inherit from `collections.Sequence` -- if they did, matlab could index into them using `p{1}`, `p(1)`, or `cell(p)`.

matlab keeps data in `F order`.  open questions:

- could this be used to avoid the `numpy.transpose` and matlab `permute` steps and make fewer copies?
- are there any implications of its usage other than changing the order of elements wrt reshaping/flattening?

there are [many ways to flatten an ndarray](http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/Why-ndarray-provides-four-ways-to-flatten-td38989.html).  which one would be fastest and make the least copies in this use case?

- `.flatten` makes a copy -- why would anyone want that?
- `.reshape((-1,))` is discouraged (i think?)
- `.ravel` makes a view -- does this make it the best choice?
- does `numpy.nditer` (or some other iterator like `.flatiter`) have exactly the same space/time efficiency as `.ravel`?
- what about `.flat`?
- `p.shape = (-1,)` might be the best, since it doesn't even copy metadata (reference?), but requires a `contiguous` array, so in general requires making a copy.  is there an approach in this use case (probably involving `F order`) that can guarantee we are contiguous?  is it discouraged for the same reasons as `.reshape((-1,))`?  how does it differ?

is it really true that a ton of layered `view`s does not significantly decrease performance of an `ndarray`?  reference?

why doesn't `numpy.array` preserve the type of an empty `array.array`? https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6028